How to exclude fields with null values using polar dataframe columns for final json output?
I am trying to read and process the bigquery table using the polars. At the end I want to write the each row as a JSON in the file such that all the fields that have null values in it (no matter how nested the JSON is) is excluded.
I am using polars to process the bigquery row. I am new to polars and could not achieve the result.
My code looks like below
def clean_json(data):
    return json.dumps(clean_record_df(data), separators=(',', ':')) 

def remove_null(data): 
    """
    Recursively remove fields with null values.
    """
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {k: clean_record_df(v) for k, v in data.items() if v is not None}
    elif isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(data, pl.Series):
        return [clean_record_df(item) for item in data if item is not None]
    return data

def process_row():
  table = pa.Table.from_batches(lazy_frames)
        df = pl.from_arrow(table)

        df = df.with_columns(
            pl.col("event_params").map_elements(clean_json, return_dtype=pl.Utf8).str.json_decode()
        )
        
        file = f"file.json"
        df.write_ndjson(file)


query = f"select * from {self.table_name}"
query_job = self.bq_client.query(query)
arrow_iterable = query_job.result().to_arrow_iterable(bqstorage_client=self.bq_storage_client)
arrows = []


for arrow in arrow_iterable:
   arrows.append(arrow)
   .....

   if num_of_rows >= 50000
      process_row(arrows)


And the final results looks like
{"event_date":"20240324","event_timestamp":1711213604759724,"event_name":"event_name","event_params":[{"key":"ignore_referrer","value":{"string_value":"true","int_value":null}}.......

As you can see the event_params still have int_value fields even though the field value is null.
And I think this is expected because as soon as I do .str.json_decode() it converts to Struct and when the field is not present in one row but its present in another row, the struct takes consideration of that as well when determining the final type.
And if I don't use .str.json_decode() then I will get something like this
{"event_date":"20240324","event_timestamp":1711213604759724,"event_name":"event_name","event_params":"[{\"key\":\"ignore_referrer\",\"value\":{\"string_value\":\"true\"}} .......

It is removing the null value fields but again it is escaping the characters which is again as expected.
So, I would like to know how can I process the row in polar such that at the end I would get at the JSON line that don't have fields with null values no matter nested it the json value is like below
{"event_date":"20240324","event_timestamp":1711213604759724,"event_name":"first_visit","event_params":[{"key":"ignore_referrer","value":{"string_value":"true"}} ................

Thanks in advance

It’s not very efficient, but depending on how large your dataframe is, it might be feasible to use pl.DataFrame.to_dicts, manually post-process the python dictionaries, and then use json.dump.

Thank you for the comment. Yeah pl.DataFrame.to_dicts might not be good because the dataframe is large and need to apply the recursive function as well. By the way I am batching the dataframe but still its big

If you are doing the json cleaning in Python, could you not write it to file from there also? You can also remove nulls when loading: json.loads(raw_json, object_hook=lambda obj: {k: v for k, v in obj.items() if v is not None}) 

thank you for the comments.
json.loads(raw_json, object_hook=lambda obj: {k: v for k, v in obj.items() if v is not None})
This was new for me. I was writing the recursive function but this made more clear and easier. Thank you for that.
As for writing to the file, since dataset is huge and need preprocessing, I wished to write to the file through polars itself if there is any way.
Right now I am using python to write to file

But you are using map_elements which means you are essentially doing for row in df.iter_rows(named=True): process(row) - As you are creating ndjson you can do the writing there too (append each result to the output file as it is guaranteed to be 1 line). It is unclear why you need Polars for that.

Polar offers you the .is_null() for values inside a dataframe series (from a column for example).
Series - Polars Documentation
It may be the case you really want to put these into Series objects, or extract them into it, or use a different structure. See note below about "dimensionality", but basically, you want something that lets you drop a whole field without batting an eye. A dataframe won't do that, unless it drops the whole column for every row. A Series will find that just fine.
You also can simply .drop_nulls() from a series.
What you might want to consider doing is the following:
def remove_null(data: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
  return data.drop_nulls()

You could also see filterpolars.Expr.filter - Polars documentation
That is for all of a dataframe.

Important note: dropping nulls, or dropping nans, on a dataframe will generally just flip things to the opposite. The only way to really effectively do this is to change the dimensionality of the object holding the values you want to disappear.

To summarize that point: You will need to make sure that you aren't trying to have things be in formats that EXPECT a field to exist. Chances are, that's what Polars is doing on the back end, enforcing the existince of a value that you don't want to exist.

I am looking at your code further and I think the issue is you may also not be going deep enough; it appears that each row entry for each column has a dictionary within it, so if you're just checking "k, v" or "entry" in series, you going to find it always true, they seem always to be populated.
You'll need to recurse inside of it, likely. Which will be VERY expensive computationally.
You may want to reconsider the best way to approach merging this data, but if you can clarify exactly what format the data is coming in as, such as where/how the event_params are being found/added

import pyarrow as pa
import polars as pl
import json

def clean_record_df(data):
    """
    Recursively remove fields with null values.
    """
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {k: clean_record_df(v) for k, v in data.items() if v is not None}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return [clean_record_df(item) for item in data if item is not None]
    return data

def clean_json(data):
    """
    Convert a dictionary to a JSON string with fields containing null values removed.
    """
    return json.dumps(clean_record_df(data), separators=(',', ':'))

def process_row(arrow_batches):
    """
    Process arrow batches, convert them to a Polars DataFrame, clean the JSON fields, and write to a file.
    """
    table = pa.Table.from_batches(arrow_batches)
    df = pl.from_arrow(table)

    # Apply clean_json to event_params column
    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("event_params").apply(lambda x: clean_json(json.loads(x)), return_dtype=pl.Utf8).str.json_decode()
    )

    # Write to a NDJSON file
    file = f"file.json"
    df.write_ndjson(file)

def main():
    query = f"select * from {self.table_name}"
    query_job = self.bq_client.query(query)
    arrow_iterable = query_job.result().to_arrow_iterable(bqstorage_client=self.bq_storage_client)
    
    arrow_batches = []
    num_of_rows = 0

    for arrow in arrow_iterable:
        arrow_batches.append(arrow)
        num_of_rows += arrow.num_rows

        if num_of_rows >= 50000:
            process_row(arrow_batches)
            arrow_batches = []
            num_of_rows = 0

    # Process remaining batches
    if num_of_rows > 0:
        process_row(arrow_batches)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The improvements in the above code are as follows:

The clean_record_df function recursively removes all fields containing null values.
The clean_json function ensures that null fields are removed when converting to a JSON string.
In the process_row function, the apply method is used to clean the JSON data in the event_params column.

